# How to interpret error of absolute magnitude of a star given data from wikipedia?

Tags: star, data-analysis, astrometry, absolute-magnitude

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spica) contains information about the star Spica in the rightmost table. A small snapshot of this table is below.

[image: table data]

In this table, the absolute magnitude is given as `−3.55 (−3.5/−1.5)`. Instead of seeing the value and error given as `value ± error`, I am thinking the error is given as it is because of absolute magnitude is given on a logarithmic scale (as opposed to linear scale). But I am not quite sure how to interpret this as an error reading. How does one interpret this reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spica (α Vir) is a binary star.
The Wikipedia article cites [Herbison-Evans et al. 1971](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1971MNRAS.151..161H/abstract), whose Table III says:

> Absolute magnitude of primary (*M<sub>v<sub>1</sub></sub>*)   -3.5±0.1
>   Absolute magnitude of secondary (*M<sub>v<sub>2</sub></sub>*)   -1.5±0.2

So the confusing "-3.55 (-3.5 / -1.5)" can be interpreted as "combined (primary / secondary)."